# Oracle - invalid name for a database object

Tags: oracle, scheduler, database

I've got this error message when executing the code below on an Oracle database:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_schedule('schema_name.package_name.procedure_name',
          repeat_interval => 'freq=daily;byhour=03;byminute=0;bysecond=0');
end;
```

I'm using dot (".") and underscore ("_") in the package and procedure name.

Does someone know if it's possible / not possible to use "." and "_" for this instruction?

Comment: Do you have permissions on the procedure from where you're running this?

Comment: The first argument is schedule's name. What are you using there?

Comment: If you create a synonym, will it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is using the "." in the package name. Oracle tends to treat this as a component indicator. Like schema.packagename.

--edit: package.packagename to schema.packagename --